# Input border has half gray color

Tags: css

In Chrome, i have a simple input with this CSS :

```
.circleInput{
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: rgb(230,230,230);
  outline-width: 0;
  border-radius: 3.5vh;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.0vw;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

In this photo you can see what happens to it :

[image]

Comment: use border-style:solid

Comment: Thanks, is it not solid by default ?

Comment: not for input element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set `border-style: solid`!

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 25px;
}

.circleInput {
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: rgb(230,230,230);
  outline-width: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 3.5vh;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.0vw;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input class="circleInput" type="text" />
</div>
```